Filter hr.employee by work_location_id using external API in PHP
How to filter hr.employee by work_location_id using external API in php?
array result: "work_location_id":[1,"First Branch"]
I want to show all employees under the work_location_id which is 1
$id = $_GET['id'];

$models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'hr.employee', 'search_read', array(array(array('work_location_id', '=', $id))));

I tried:
array(array(array('work_location_id', '=', $id))) //not working
array(array(array('work_location_id[0]', '=', $id))) //not working

I want to show all employees under the work_location_id which is 1

Do you get any Error message? And which Odoo version you're asking for?

hello sir thank you for your response i'm using version 15 sir and there is no error message just showing []

What user do you use on the call? Because it's possible, that this user does not have sufficient rights to read all employees.

i'm using admin sir there is no problem with the account the call is working if  field is not an array. like id. as i mention this is the result "work_location_id":[1,"First Branch"]  how to equal or get the work_location_id  which is 1 to equal it to id post request  example array(array(array('work_location_id[0]', '=', $id))) but it is not working

you have 2 differents operations of search base odoo.
Search: Gives you the ids from records.
Search_read: Gives you apart from id of records, needed fields.
the use of search_read is the following.
search_read(fields, domain, offset=0, limit=80, order=None, context=None)


$model = 'hr.employee'; 
$fields = array('name');
$domain = array('work_location_id', '=', $id); // Make sure $id is a int and a valid id.
$options = array($fields,$domain,0,50);

$records = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, $model, 'search_read',$options);

about the domain you shared
array('work_location_id[0]', '=', $id);

it will never work, because 'work_location_id[0]' is not a field that the record 'hr.employee' have.
